# How to get a folder name in linux bash from a directory

Tags: linux, bash, directory

There will be directory which will have any number folder and may be files, I just need pick one random folder and need to process it ( move the folders , etc ..) I need process folder one by one. Need to ignore if there is any files.

I am tiring with below code able to get folder name but , seems there some hidden character or some thing which not giving proper output.

```
PROCESSING_FOLDER_NAME= ls -l /ecom/bin/catalogUpload/input/TNF-EU/ | grep '^d' | cut -d ' ' -f23 | head -1

#PROCESSING_FOLDER_NAME= echo $PROCESSING_FOLDER_NAME | tr -d '\n\r'

#PROCESSING_FOLDER_NAME=${PROCESSING_FOLDER_NAME%$'\n'}

#echo "PROCESSING_FOLDER_NAME is/$PROCESSING_FOLDER_NAME "

echo  "/ecom/bin/catalogUpload/input/TNF-EU/$PROCESSING_FOLDER_NAME/"
```

output

```
Thanks_giving_Dec_08
/ecom/bin/catalogUpload/input/TNF-EU//
```

I am expecting the output should be /ecom/bin/catalogUpload/input/TNF-EU/Thanks_giving_Dec_08/

Here is my bash version.

```
GNU bash, version 4.2.50(1)-release (powerpc-ibm-aix6.1.2.0)
```

I mainly need the folder name (not full path) in variable, As the folder name which is processing need be use for emails to notify other, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a random folder from a list of folders,
first put the list of folders in an array:

```
list=(/ecom/bin/catalogUpload/input/TNF-EU/*/)
```

Next, get a random index using the `$RANDOM` variable of the shell,
modulo the size of the list:

```
((index = RANDOM % ${#list[@]}))
```

Print the value at the selected index:

```
echo "${list[index]}"
```

To get just the name of the directory without the full path, you can use the `basename` command:

```
basename "${list[index]}"
```

---

As for what's wrong with the original script:

- To store the result of a command in a variable, the syntax is `name=$(cmd)` instead of `name= cmd`
- Do not parse the output of `ls`, it's not reliable
- To get directories in a directory, you can use glob patterns like `*` ending with `/`, as in the above example `*/`.

Comment: thank you, now i got some more idea, actually i need only the folder ( not any files , the directory may have files) and I need the name of the folder not the full path. And some reason name=$(cmd) syntax to store  result is not working in that bash shell it is giving error, could you please help me out

Comment: @Krushna I updated my answer to get only the directory name without the full path. As for the `name=$(cmd)` syntax, it has to work. And if you say "it is giving error" but you don't say what is that error, then it's too hard to help.

Comment: Thank you Janos I got the script to work, name=$(cmd) syntax here is the error:bash: Thanks_giving_Dec_08: command not found
It is tiring to execute the output and saying command not found

Comment: @Krushna What I meant with `name=$(cmd)` is that instead of `PROCESSING_FOLDER_NAME= ls -l ...` you must write `PROCESSING_FOLDER_NAME=$(ls -l ...)`. The `cmd` in `$(cmd)` must be a command to run. Based on your output I think you are using some value there that is not an executable command.